# How do I login Youtube using the Metro code

Tags: youtube, microsoft-metro

I am using the Gdata API to log in to Youtube in Desktop mode in Win8.

Now I have a question about logging in to Youtube using VS2012 with C# in Metro mode in Win8.

Could anyone provide a hint, or tell me how to do this?

I don't have any idea about how to log in to Youtube in Metro mode in Win8.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this myself but Leon Cullen has an article on how to authenticate using OAuth on WinRT, [Using OAuth 2 in WinRT using C#](http://leoncullens.nl/post/2012/09/26/Using-OAuth-2-in-WinRT-using-Csharp-it-has-never-been-easier-before.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the GData API [isn't presently compatible with Windows 8 Metro apps](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/issues/detail?id=620).  If you have sufficient time, however, you could get a copy of their source code [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) and extract from it what you need to get your WinRT app running.

Edit:  Here's a sample project demonstrating how to connect to an OAuth client:  [Web Authentication Broker Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122)

If you'd prefer to use a separate API to handle this for you, there are a few in various stages of development:

[Chq.OAuth](https://github.com/myquay/Chq.OAuth)

[Metro OAuth Utils](http://metrooauth.codeplex.com/releases/view/91224)